# how to curl with query string parameter in format of "filter[name]=foo"

Tags: http, curl

Here is an api on my server:

https://server/api/v1/products?filter[name]=foo

this works well when I access it via browser, and it works well with the following two methods:

```
$ cat /tmp/x
{"filter": {"name": "foo"}}

$ curl -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -k -s --negotiate -u : -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "@/tmp/x" https://server/api/v1/products
{"name": "foo", ...}

$ curl -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -k -s --negotiate -u : -d "filter[name]=foo" https://server/api/v1/products
{"name": "foo", ...}
```

Now I'm trying to do it with:

```
$ curl -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -k -s --negotiate -u : https://server/api/v1/products?filter[name]=foo
$ echo $?
3
```

it fails with error code 3, which stands for "URL malformed. The syntax was not correct."

How should I specify the query string parameters in the url?

Comment: Quote the URL perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string needs to be [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) so it has to look like this:

```
https://server/api/v1/products?filter%5Bname%5D=foo
```

[asciitable.com](http://asciitable.com).